# Resonance curve of a Harmonic oscillator

Tags: energy, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, resonance

The resonance curve of a damped harmonic oscillator has a peak at the resonant frequency $\omega_0$. If the damping coefficient $\gamma$ is more then the peak is lower, compared to before, i.e the amplitude is lower. As amplitude directly corresponds to square root of energy, can we make a correlation between frequency and energy of the mechanical system?

Comment: No, because it is the amplitude to be correlated, not frequency.

Comment: Why do you bring the resonance into this? For any harmonic oscillator the energy depends on both amplitude and frequency.  You can find the formula on wiki.